# Cannot instantiate php object

Tags: php, class, oop, interface

I have a PHP interface and a class that implements it.
When i'm trying to instatiate the object the (web) page become completely white, it doesn't display any error even if display errors is "on" and if error reporting is set to E_ALL, nothing is reported nor in the php error log or apache error log.

This is the code.

```
<?php
    namespace it\MyCompany\OtherCompany\System;

    interface IInsertUserQueryStrategy{
        /**
         * 
         * @param User $u
         * @param array $defaultParameters 
         * @param string $ua
         */
        public function insert(User $u, $defaultParameters = array(), $ua = null);
    }
```

The class that implements it

```
<?php
namespace it\MyCompany\OtherCompany\ICF\System;

use it\MyCompany\OtherCompany\System\IInsertUserQueryStrategy;

class ICFInsertUserQueryStrategy implements IInsertUserQueryStrategy{

    public function insert(ICFUser $u, $defaultParameters = array(), $ua = null){

        $u->setActivationKey();

        $parameters = array_merge($defaultParameters,
                                  array (ICFUserPeer::VERIFICATION_KEY => $u->getActivationKey(),
                                         ICFUserPeer::NOME              => $u->getNome(),
                                         ICFUserPeer::COGNOME           => $u->getCognome(),
                                         ICFUserPeer::EMAIL             => $u->getEmail(),
                                         ICFUserPeer::CELLULARE         => $u->getCellulare(),
                                         ICFUserPeer::PASSWORD          => $u->getPassword(),
                                         ICFUserPeer::PRIVACY           => (int)$u->getPrivacyMarketing(),
                                         ICFUserPeer::PDV               => $u->getPuntoVendita(),
                                         ICFUserPeer::FIDELITY          => $u->getFidelity(),
                                         ICFUserPeer::TIPOCARD          => $u->getTipoCard(),
                                         ICFUserPeer::TIPO_AZIONE       => UserPeer::WS_CONSUMERHANDLER_INSERT));


        if (! is_null ( $ua )) {
            $parameters = array_merge ( $parameters, $ua );
        }

        return $parameters;
    }

}
```

I use composer and the autoload system, other classes/files contained in the same directory of these two classes are loaded without problem.

```
$is = new ICFInsertUserQueryStrategy(); //This generate some error wtih blank page
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: This is exactly the problem!
I don't know, it only stops the page, just a white page with no error reported.
Trying to print a var_dump just after the $is = new ICFInsertUserQueryStrategy() it doesn't show nothing.

Comment: Try setting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` before trying to instate.

Comment: error_reporting(-1);

Comment: Where exactly are you calling this class? in the same file or any other file. If in any other file then use new \it\MyCompany\OtherCompany\ICF\System\ICFInsertUserQueryStrategy()

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. Now i have the error even if i have no idea whye the error_reporting is overwritten while executin, i will indagate. 

By the way it was an error of type definitions in User class extended by the ICFUser.

Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the definition of insert method should be same you can not use ICFUser

Comment: You can if it `extend`s `User`.

Comment: ICFUser extends User ?

Comment: can you provide me an example as i tried its not working ?

Comment: as i know and according to document :  The class implementing the interface must use the exact same method signatures as are defined in the interface. Not doing so will result in a fatal error.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I confused it with `abstract` class. Good point.

Comment: ICFUser extends User yes.

In constructor of User i pass an object ( Ex. __construct(MyObject $o = null) ) but in ICFUser constructor i wrote (typo) __construct($var, MyObject $o = false). This constructor calls the parent::__constructor so passing false instead of null it raised an error.

My problem was that the entire system didn't show the error.

Comment: And, yes, the signature must be the same. In the interface there is User so i cannot pass ICFUser to the insert method even if it extends it.